# Progress indicator not stopping inside TabView in android platform nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Iam working the nativescript application.I have TabView with three tabs,in each tab i have progress indicator for showing api is loading and also hide the indicator after response came from api.In ios platform the indicator hide perfectly but android platform the indicator was not hide.How to solve the issue?

My TabView html code is:

```
<TabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)" selectedTabTextColor="#40053e" androidTabsPosition="bottom" androidOffscreenTabLimit="0" iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Security', iconSource: 'res://lock'}">
        <StackLayout>
           <security></security>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Personal', iconSource: 'res://boy'}">
        <StackLayout>
           <personal></personal>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Payment', iconSource: 'res://card'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <payment></payment>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

My TabViw ts code:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TabView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view";
import { Page } from "ui/page";




@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "profiletab",
    templateUrl: 'profiletab.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['profiletab.component.css']
})

export class  ProfileTabComponent implements OnInit {
    private tabSelectedIndex:number;
    private selectedTabName;


    tabview:TabView;

    constructor(private page:Page) {
        this.tabSelectedIndex = 0;
        this.selectedTabName = "Security Info";
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        // this.tabview=<TabView>this.page.getViewById("tabcontrol");
        // this.tabview.androidOffscreenTabLimit=1;
    }

    onIndexChanged(args){
        let tabView = <TabView>args.object;
        switch (tabView.selectedIndex) {
            case 0:
                this.selectedTabName = "Security Info";
                break;
            case 1:
                this.selectedTabName = "Personal Info";
                break;
            case 2:
                this.selectedTabName = "Payment Info";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

I will create indicator inside the tab1,tab2,tab3 like:

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.loadCountries();
    }
loadCountries(){
        var _this = this;
        if (!this.conn.getConnectionStatus()) {
            Toast.makeText("Please check your internet connection").show();
            return;
        }
        Indicator.showIndicator("Loading Please Wait...");
        this.authenticationService.Get_Countries_List().then(function(response){
            _this.renderData(response);
           }
       });
    }



renderData(values){
this.authenticationService.Get_States_List(_this.dataService.userProfile.contact[0].country).then(function(response){
                        Indicator.hideIndicator();
       }
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code how are you trying to stop the indicator?

Comment: is it the nativescript-loading-indicator ?

Comment: Yes..Inside Tabview the indicator was not hide

Comment: i was shared the code @ Narendra Mongiya

Comment: Indicator.hideIndicator(); ? that loader has hide(); only

Comment: no hideindicator method is there..My question is inside tabview the three tabs indicator were not hiding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185395/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-arigarasuthan).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to create different instances while showing & hiding indicator. You must call `hide` of same `LoadingIndicator` instance on which you did call `show`.

Source: [https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-loading-indicator/issues/58](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-loading-indicator/issues/58#issuecomment-448118465)

Also here is an [example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=mG98x6&v=1) that demonstrates how you can do this without a plugin and always keep reference of current loading indicator no matter how many times you call show / hide simultaneously. You may even apply similar logic to maintain your `LoadingIndicator` instance with plugin. Refer `ui-helper.ts` and `home-page.ts`.

FYI, by nature of platform iOS seems to use a singleton which is why it works there even if you create multiple `LoadingIndicator`. But with Android a new progress dialog is created every time when you call show, so you must call hide on same instance.

Also as you are using Angular, I would suggest you to take advantage of framework features like Http Interceptors so you wouldn't have to create / handle indicator for each tab or each api call separately.

Comment: How can i preload the one tab in tabview?.I have 3 tabs in tabview